# KeyError: <class '__main__.Page2'> in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I do know that there are a few other questions similar to mine, but none of the answers work. I am building an application in tkinter, and when I try to use the lambda : self.show_frame(frame) method it doesn't work and it says KeyError: <class '**main**.Page2'>

note that the function **init** is indented, it just didn't indent on stackoverflow.

```
class tkinterApp(Tk): 
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
    # __init__ function for class Tk 
    Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 
 
    # creating a container 
    container = Frame(self)   
    container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)  

    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1) 
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1) 

    

    # initializing frames to an empty array 
    self.frames = {}   

    # iterating through a tuple consisting 
    # of the different page layouts 
    for F in (StartPage, Page1): 

        frame = F(container, self) 

        # initializing frame of that object from 
        # startpage, page1, page2 respectively with  
        # for loop 
        self.frames[F] = frame  

        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew") 
    
    mainMenu = Menu(self)
    self.config(menu=mainMenu)

    location = Menu(mainMenu)
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label="Quick Location", menu=location)
    location.add_command(label="SignUp", command=lambda : self.show_frame(Page1))

    #the code I am having an issue with
    location.add_command(label="SignIn", command=lambda : self.show_frame(Page2))
    #the code I am having an issue with

    location.add_command(label="Homepage", command=lambda : self.show_frame(StartPage))

    location.add_command(label="Quit", command=self.quit)
    
    self.show_frame(StartPage) 

# to display the current frame passed as 
# parameter 
def show_frame(self, cont): 
    frame = self.frames[cont] 
    frame.tkraise()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include `Page2` in the `for F in (...)`:

```
for F in (StartPage, Page1, Page2):
    ...
```

Comment: thank you so much, I just sometimes miss those little details.