# Why the interpreter outputs a namerror in tkinter when I try to call the function in another file

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have the `Win.py` file debugged and it worked well. However, according to @Matiiss, I will write the function like

```
def func():
    lbl = ImageLabel(root)
    lbl.pack()
    lbl.load('D:/Personal/Game/Win.gif')
```

inside the main file, which is `start2.py`, but when I inserted the function inside the command, python outputs an error like `NameError: name 'root' is not defined`. I am not sure whether I need to change `root` into something else or not because I indeed didn't see `root` anywhere in either of the file. The following is the codes for the `Win.py` file.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from itertools import count, cycle


class ImageLabel(tk.Label):
    def load(self, im):
        if isinstance(im, str):
            im = Image.open(im)
        frames = []

        try:
            for i in count(1):
                frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy()))
                im.seek(i)
        except EOFError:
            pass
        self.frames = cycle(frames)

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']
        except:
            self.delay = 100

        if len(frames) == 1:
            self.config(image=next(self.frames))
        else:
            self.next_frame()

    def unload(self):
        self.config(image=None)
        self.frames = None

    def next_frame(self):
        if self.frames:
            self.config(image=next(self.frames))
            self.after(self.delay, self.next_frame)
```

I don't know where is the `root`, but I don't know which argument to be added inside the `lbl=ImageLabel()`.
The codes for `start2.py`, with correct indent.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygame
from playsound import playsound
from Win import ImageLabel
display_width = 1000
display_height = 500
# Set up the display size

white = (255, 255, 255)  # White
red = (255, 0, 0)  # Red button background
picture = 'D:/Personal/Game UI.jpg'  # The location of the picture

pygame.init()  # Initialize class+



class Button(object):  # Button class
    def __init__(self, text, color, x=None, y=None, **kwargs):
        self.surface = font.render(text, True, color)

        self.WIDTH = self.surface.get_width()
        self.HEIGHT = self.surface.get_height()
        if 'centered_x' in kwargs and kwargs['centered_x']:  # Show the place that a button will show up (x-axis)
            self.x = display_width // 2 - self.WIDTH // 2
        else:
            self.x = x
        if 'centered_y' in kwargs and kwargs['centered_y']:  # Show the place that a button will show up (y-axis)
            self.y = display_height // 2 - self.HEIGHT // 2
        else:
            self.y = y

    def display(self):
        screen.blit(self.surface, (self.x, self.y))  # Can't assign a value to a function

    def check_click(self, position):  # Track mouse behavior to show highlights
        x_match = position[0] > self.x and position[0] < self.x + self.WIDTH
        y_match = position[1] > self.y and position[1] < self.y + self.HEIGHT
        if x_match and y_match:
            return True
        else:
            return False


def start_screen():  # This function is used to load background and music
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    game_title = font.render("Start", True, white)
    screen.blit(game_title, (display_width // 2 - game_title.get_width() // 2, 150))
    play_button = Button("Play", red, None, 350, centered_x=True)  # Start the game
    exit_button = Button("Exit", white, None, 400, centered_x=True)  # Exit the game
    play_button.display()
    exit_button.display()
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:  # A conditional reading from while loop
        if play_button.check_click(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            play_button = Button('Play', red, None, 350, centered_x=True)
        else:
            play_button = Button('Play', white, None, 350, centered_x=True)
        if exit_button.check_click(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            exit_button = Button("Exit", red, None, 400, centered_x=True)
        else:
            exit_button = Button("Exit", red, None, 400, centered_x=True)
        play_button.display()
        exit_button.display()
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                raise SystemExit
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            if play_button.check_click(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                break
            if exit_button.check_click(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                break


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))  # The use of the functions above
bg = pygame.image.load(picture)
font_addr = pygame.font.get_default_font()
font = pygame.font.Font(font_addr, 36)
start_screen()

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)  # Font


# TODO: sound is defined here
def fail1():
    playsound("D:/Personal/Game/wha-wha.mp3", block=False)


def fail2():
    playsound("D:/Personal/Game/Nope-Sound-Effect.wav", block=False)  # TODO: bug here, use wav format


def fail3():
    playsound("D:/Personal/Game/friday-damn.mp3", block=False)


def fail4():
    playsound("D:/Personal/Game/export_4.mp3", block=False)


def fail5():
    playsound("D:/Personal/Game/Aww.mp3", block=False)


def fail6():
    playsound("D:/Personal/Game/Laughing.mp3", block=False)


def fail7():
    playsound("D:/Personal/Game/Incorrect.mp3", block=False)


def give_up():
    playsound("D:/Personal/Game/Fail.mp3", block=False)


def try_again():
    playsound("D:/Personal/Game/Here-we-go.mp3", block=False)


def success1():
    playsound("D:/Personal/Game/Yah.mp3", block=False)


def gif():
    top = tk.Toplevel(app)
    lbl = ImageLabel(top)
    lbl.pack()
    lbl.load('D:/Personal/Game/Win.gif') 


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):  # Define a class for the tk windows
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # Base properties of tk windows
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        '''https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64470478/keyerror-class-main-page2-in-python-tkinter For range means 
        that the buttons will be loaded for multiple times, whenever a new option is added, for range needs to be 
        defined. '''

        for F in (
                StartPage, MCQ, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8, Q9, Q10, Failure, Success,
                Credits):  # TODO: add the class number into the for loop here
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):  # Start page

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This will test your chemistry ability. Ready to start?", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Enter",
                           command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(MCQ), try_again()])  # This will show the next window
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Cancel",
                            command=lambda: controller.destroy())  # This will close the window
        button2.pack()


class MCQ(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!! Question 1: What is proton number equal to?", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Atomic mass",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Sorry, you died. Better luck next time!"),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail1()])
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Number of moles",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Sorry, you died. Better luck next time!"),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail1()])
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Atomic number",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Q2))
        button3.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(Credits), give_up()])
        button4.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):
        print(choice)


class Q2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!! Question 2: Which of the two statements describes the word "
                                    "endothermic?", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Give out heat", command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Wah-ah-ah-ah..."),
                                                                         controller.show_frame(Failure), fail2()])
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Take in heat", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Q3))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Give up",
                            command=lambda: self.correspondingBehavior("Don't give up!"))
        button3.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(Credits), give_up()])
        button4.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):
        print(choice)


class Q3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!! Question :3 he symbol Ag stands for which element?", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Gold",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Wah-ah-ah-ah... EPIC FAIL!!! Gold is Au!"),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail2()])
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Silver", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Q4))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Hydrogen",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Wah-ah-ah-ah... EPIC FAIL!!! Hydrogen is H!"),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail2()])
        button3.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(Credits), give_up()])
        button4.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):
        print(choice)


class Q4(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!! Question 3: Organic chemistry is the study of the compounds that "
                                    "make up living organisms. All organic molecules contain:", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Carbon only",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("WHH! Check your book.."),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail3()])
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Carbon and nitrogen",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Wah-ah-ah-ah... You died!"),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail3()])
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Carbon and hydrogen",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Q5))
        button3.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(Credits), give_up()])
        button4.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):
        print(choice)


class Q5(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!!A molecule with the formula C3H8 is a(n)", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="hexane",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Nope, it's C6H14"),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail4()])
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="propane", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Q6))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="butane",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Nope, it's C4H10"),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail4()])
        button3.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(Credits), give_up()])
        button4.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):
        print(choice)


class Q6(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!!A substance that speeds up the rate of a chemical reaction without "
                                    "undergoing any change itself "
                                    "is known as a _______", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="catalyst",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Q7))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="cation", command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Wah-ah-ah-ah... What a "
                                                                                             "pity! But cation is a "
                                                                                             "positive charge."),
                                                                  controller.show_frame(Failure), fail4()])
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="counter ion",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Nope, it's the ion that accompanies an ionic "
                                                                        "species in order to maintain electric "
                                                                        "neutrality."), controller.show_frame(Failure),
                                             fail4()])
        button3.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(Credits), give_up()])
        button4.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):
        print(choice)


class Q7(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!! All of the following are amino acids except:",
                         font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Tryptophan",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Nope, adenine is a nucleic acid, not an "
                                                                        "amino acid."), controller.show_frame(Failure),
                                             fail6()])
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Tyrosine",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Wah-ah-ah-ah... Adenine is a nucleic acid, "
                                                                        "not an amino acid."),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail6()])
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Adenine",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Q8))
        button3.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(Credits), give_up()])
        button4.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):
        print(choice)


class Q8(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!!A mole contains Avogadro's number of items. What is Avogadro's number?",
                         font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="6023",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Wrong...Check your chemistry book"),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail5()])
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="C. 6.02 x 10^-23",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Wah-ah-ah-ah... What a "
                                                                        "pity! But the value is larger than that..."),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail5()])
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="6.023 x 10^23",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Q9))
        button3.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(Credits), give_up()])
        button4.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):
        print(choice)


class Q9(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!!The person given credit for developing the first modern periodic "
                                    "table is",
                         font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Democritus",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Wrong...He was famous for the formulation of "
                                                                        "an atomic theory of the universe"),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail7()])
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Mendeleev",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Q10))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Thomson",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Wah-ah-ah-ah... What a "
                                                                        "pity! He is the one who did a detailed study "
                                                                        "of cathode rays and proved the existence of "
                                                                        "the electron in atoms"),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail7()])
        button3.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(Credits), give_up()])
        button4.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):
        print(choice)


class Q10(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!! Does group or period in the periodic table represent outer shell "
                                    "electrons?",
                         font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Period",
                            command=lambda: [self.correspondingBehavior("Wrong...You can draw it out and see"),
                                             controller.show_frame(Failure), fail7()])
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Group",
                            command=lambda: (controller.show_frame(Success)))  # TODO: find a way
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(Credits), give_up()])
        button3.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):
        print(choice)


class Success(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Yay! You have passed my chemistry challenge! Would you like to continue?",
                         font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Continue", command=[gif(), success1()])
        button1.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=lambda: controller.destroy())
        button2.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):  # Comment
        print(choice)


class Failure(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Sorry about that, but you failed. Would you like to try again?",
                         font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Yes", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(MCQ), try_again()])
        button1.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="No", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Credits))
        button2.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self, choice):
        print(choice)

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
'''
Now the codes are in a mess and I am going to write the comments after debugging.
```

Comment: You may need to pass a tkinter container (e.g. `Frame`, `Toplevel`, `Tk`, etc) to tell where `ImageLabel` is being put.  Therefore it depends on how  `start2.py` is designed. So post the relevant code in `start2.py` as well.

Comment: That guy told me to put ```Toplevel``` in the ```ImageLabel```, but what's the difference  between each container?

Comment: Instance of `Toplevel` and `Tk` is a window, whereas instance of `Frame` is a container that should be put inside a window or another container.

Comment: In the full code there is this line `command=[gif(), success1()]` and You seem to have forgotten to put `lambda :` there which means that those functions will be called immediately before `app` is defined, so write `command=lambda: [gif(), success1()]`

Comment: Now it outputs an attributeerror: ```AttributeError: 'Toplevel' object has no attribute 'copy'```, so does that mean that I should change toplevel object to something else?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no information on `start2.py`, below is an example that you may put in `start2.py` based on your posted codes:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from Win import ImageLabel

def func():
    lbl = ImageLabel(root)
    lbl.pack()
    lbl.load("D:/Personal/Game/Win.gif")

root = tk.Tk() # the root window for the ImageLabel
func()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific. I just told "parent" can be `Toplevel` or `Frame` without specifying anything and just put `root` there.